# Need suggestions in generating sql query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle9i

We have below type of records in a table:

**table_example:**

```
id|desc|is_parent_record|parent_id
1|parent record|yes|
2|child record|no|1
3|standalone record|no
```

we want to retrieve all records in below format

```
id|parent id|desc
1| |parent record
2|1|child record
3| |no parent, standalone record
```

Any suggestions and help for generating sql query ?

Thanks,
Rajesh

Answer (score 0):

Use simply hierarchical query with `case when` and `connect_by_isleaf`:

```
select id, parent_id, 
       case when level = 1 and connect_by_isleaf = 1 
            then 'no parent, '||descr 
            else descr
       end descr
  from t
  connect by prior id = parent_id
  start with parent_id is null
```

**<sup>[demo](http://rextester.com/MPL27307)</sup>**

```
    ID  PARENT_ID DESCR
------ ---------- ----------------------------
     1            parent record
     2          1 child record
     3            no parent, standalone record
```